# Stuck creating a php/javascript countdown timer

Tags: javascript, php, timer, setinterval

I have been struggling to get my head around this for a while now.

I am attempting to create a countdown timer. Eventually I want it to reset after every 5 hours starting from 8am. But for now I can't figure out if im setting the hours, minutes and seconds correctly to count down together properly.

This is my code so far:

```
<?php
    $timeTo  = strtotime('08:00:00').'<br />';
                $timeNow = strtotime('now').'<br />';
                $differenceInSeconds = $timeTo - $timeNow;
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var s= "<?php Print($differenceInSeconds);?>";
                var h= Math.floor(s/3600);
                s-= h*3600;
                var m= Math.floor(s/60);
                s -= m*60;
                var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second
                    function timer()
                    {

                      s=s-1;
                      if(h >= 0 && m >= 0 && s <= -1){
                        m=m-1;
                        s=59;
                        if(h>= 0 && m < 0 && s <= -1){
                            h=h-1;
                            m=59;
                            s=59;
                              if (s <= -1)
                              {

                                 //counter ended, reset counter


                                 return;
                              }
                          }
                        }
                        //Do code for showing the number of seconds here
                          document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=(h <= 0 ? ' ' : h+"hr ")+(m <= 0 ? ' ' : m+"min ")+(s < 10 ? '0'+s : s+"secs "); // watch for spelling
                    }
            </script>
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree here? I am new to times and javascript so finding it difficult.

Answer (score 3):

I will not answer this. I will just try to lead you to the answer.

1. Note that `s <= -1` is logically equivalent to `s < 0`. There is no confusion about it. Use the second one, it looks more clean.
2. `s=59;` and in the next line how on earth will `if(h>= 0 && m < 0 &&` **s <= -1** `)` ever evaluate to `true` ?

Similar other logical mistakes are present as well. Take some time and fix this. If you fix this on your own then you're one step closer to becoming a good programmer.

Happy Coding... :)

Comment: Although answering `I wont answer` may be incorrect, still +1 for invoking self-education